# How to properly create a popup component in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, popup, vuejs3

As part of becoming a better Vue programmer, I am trying to implement a popup similar to [Popper](https://popper.js.org/) with a clean and Vueish architecture. Here is a simple schematic that I came up with:

[image: Heading]

So basically there is a target component, which is the reference for the popup's position. The popup can be positioned above, below, right and left of the target, therefore I will need to have access to the target element in my popup. Also, the target can be an arbitrary component. It can be a simple button or span, but also something much more complex.

Then there is the popup itself, which will be put into a modal at the end of the body, It contains the actual content. The content again can be an arbitrary component.

I have a working implementation of the popup, but the basic structure seems to be far from perfect. I am using two slots, one for the target element and one for the content.

Here is what I have come up with so far for the template:

```
<template>
  <div ref="targetContainer">
    <slot name="target"></slot>
  </div>
  <teleport to="body">
    <div v-show="show" class="modal" ref="modal">
      <div ref="popover" class="popover" :style="{top: popoverTop + 'px', left: popoverLeft + 'px'}">
        <slot name="content"></slot>
      </div>
    </div>
  </teleport>
</template>
```

There are several issues with this that I am not really happy with.

1. Using the popup is not very simple

When using this popup in another component, two `<template>` tags are rquired. This is ungly and not very intuitive. A very simple use case looks like this:

```
 <modal :show="showPopup" @close="showPopup=false">
    <template v-slot:target>
      <button @click="showPopup=true"></button>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:content>
      <div>Hello World!</div>
    </template>
  </modal>
```

2. The target is wrapped in another `<div>`

This is done to get access to the target element, that I need for the layout. In `mounted()` I am referencing the target element like this:

```
let targetElement = this.$refs.targetContainer.children[0];
```

Is this really the best way to do this? I would like to get rid of the wrapping `<div>` element, which just asks for unintended side effects.

The best solution would be to get rid of one slot and somehow reference the target element in another way because I only need its layout information, it does not have to be rendered inside the popover component.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What you said last is true, you can pass your target's #id via prop on your popper component, i.e. <modal target="myTarget" /> then in your element access it as document.getElementById("#" + this.target). I must say creating a popper from scratch will be very challenging, good luck :D

Comment: Thanks, this lead me to an even better approach. I can just pass the ref of a component in the parent component as targetRef prop. Then I can access the target element through this.$parent.$refs[this.targetRef]  This completely solves my issues and I can even avoid using ids!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, which was inspired by a comment on my question and which I think is worth sharing.

Instead of putting the target element into a slot, I am now passing its ref as a prop, which makes things much cleaner.

The popover component's template now looks like this.

```js
<template>
  <teleport to="body">
    <div v-show="show" class="modal" ref="modal">
      <div ref="popover" class="popover" :style="{top: popoverTop + 'px', left: popoverLeft + 'px'}">
        <slot ref="content"></slot>
      </div>
    </div>
  </teleport>
</template>
```

I has a `targetRef`prop, so the component can be simply used like this:

```html
<div ref="myTargetElement" @click="isPopupVisible=true">
</div>
<modal :show="isPopupVisible" @close="isPopupVisible=false" targetRef="myTargetElement">
    <!-- popup content goes here -->
</modal>
```

And after mounting I can access the target element like this:

```js
let targetElement = this.$parent.$refs[this.targetRef];
```

I like this solution a lot. However, ideas, advice or words of caution are still highly welcome.

Comment: It's frustrating when you guys insert code with no highlighting. Hard to read :(

Comment: @Chris This can certainly be said in a nicer way, but you are correct. Just added highlighting.